# Tool for fetching the Http Response from mobile device

Tags: mobile, fetch, httpresponse

I need a cellphone application that sends a http request and then saves the http response.

The reason I want this is to make sure that the response sent from our server to the mobile is the same as the response the mobile receive. We are currently expecting that some mobile operators are modifying the response. So we would like to know what they modify.

I have access to a bunch of phones: but I would prefer Symbian s60 or windows mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Windows Mobile application, check out "Debugging a HTTP Request" at [this sample telnet client (CodeProject)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/WiMoTelnetClient.aspx)